# Using one baked texture uv map for other objects of the same overall geometry

Tags: uv

I have multiple objects that are walls, all using the same texture, do l have to bake a separate UV map for each or can l reuse the first map, and then apply it to each other wall, there is a link object function, tried it, but only transferred the material not the t baked texture. 
regards

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
1. -name all textures
2. -select object you want material assigned to 
3. switch to edit mode on the selected object.
4. go to the materials subsection on the tools bar
5. select material you want on the object
6. press assign - and the material is assigned to the selected object -

material is assigned to the object, and can be viewed in the texture view..
repeat as many times as required.
QED